How to add my custom tune block to all tools in editorjs
I am trying to do a POC in editorjs. I am trying to explore if this can be used as an editor for my application. So Mostly i need paragraph, header, list. So i can concentrate on that entirely. This is my editorjs code,
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import EditorJS from "@editorjs/editorjs";
import Header from "@editorjs/header";
import List from "@editorjs/list";
import BackgroundColorTune from "./BackgroundColorTune"; // Import your custom tune

const EditorComponent = () => {
  const editorInstance = useRef(null);
  const editorContainer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Initialize Editor.js
    editorInstance.current = new EditorJS({
        holder: editorContainer.current,
        tools: {
          header: {
            class: Header,
            inlineToolbar: true,
          },
          list: {
            class: List,
            inlineToolbar: true,
          }
          // Add more tools here as needed
        },
        tunes: {
          backgroundColor: BackgroundColorTune, // Associate the tune with a name
        }
      });

    // Cleanup on component unmount
    return () => {
      if (editorInstance.current) {
        editorInstance.current.destroy();
        editorInstance.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Editor.js Integration with Global Custom Block Tune</h2>
      <div
        id="editorjs"
        ref={editorContainer}
        style={{ border: "1px solid #ccc", padding: "10px" }}
      >
        {/* Editor.js will be rendered here */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditorComponent;

And this is my custom tune block class which i created,
class BackgroundColorTune {
    constructor({ api, data, block }) {
      this.api = api;
      this.block = block;
      this.data = data || {};
    }
  
    // Render method for the tune button
    renderSettings() {
        const settings = [
          {
            name: "withBorder",
            icon: `<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.8 10.592v2.043h2.35v2.138H15.8v2.232h-2.25v-2.232h-2.4v-2.138h2.4v-2.28h2.25v.237h1.15-1.15zM1.9 8.455v-3.42c0-1.154.985-2.09 2.2-2.09h4.2v2.137H4.15v3.373H1.9zm0 2.137h2.25v3.325H8.3v2.138H4.1c-1.215 0-2.2-.936-2.2-2.09v-3.373zm15.05-2.137H14.7V5.082h-4.15V2.945h4.2c1.215 0 2.2.936 2.2 2.09v3.42z"/></svg>`
          },
          {
            name: "stretched",
            icon: `<svg width="17" height="10" viewBox="0 0 17 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M13.568 5.925H4.056l1.703 1.703a1.125 1.125 0 0 1-1.59 1.591L.962 6.014A1.069 1.069 0 0 1 .588 4.26L4.38.469a1.069 1.069 0 0 1 1.512 1.511L4.084 3.787h9.606l-1.85-1.85a1.069 1.069 0 1 1 1.512-1.51l3.792 3.791a1.069 1.069 0 0 1-.475 1.788L13.514 9.16a1.125 1.125 0 0 1-1.59-1.591l1.644-1.644z"/></svg>`
          },
          {
            name: "withBackground",
            icon: `<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M10.043 8.265l3.183-3.183h-2.924L4.75 10.636v2.923l4.15-4.15v2.351l-2.158 2.159H8.9v2.137H4.7c-1.215 0-2.2-.936-2.2-2.09v-8.93c0-1.154.985-2.09 2.2-2.09h10.663l.033-.033.034.034c1.178.04 2.12.96 2.12 2.089v3.23H15.3V5.359l-2.906 2.906h-2.35zM7.951 5.082H4.75v3.201l3.201-3.2zm5.099 7.078v3.04h4.15v-3.04h-4.15zm-1.1-2.137h6.35c.635 0 1.15.489 1.15 1.092v5.13c0 .603-.515 1.092-1.15 1.092h-6.35c-.635 0-1.15-.489-1.15-1.092v-5.13c0-.603.515-1.092 1.15-1.092z"/></svg>`
          }
        ];
        const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    
        settings.forEach((tune) => {
          let button = document.createElement("div");
    
          button.classList.add("cdx-settings-button");
          button.innerHTML = tune.icon;
          wrapper.appendChild(button);
        });
    
        return wrapper;
      }
  
    // Save method to preserve tune data
    save() {
      return this.data;
    }
  }
  
  export default BackgroundColorTune;
  

How to add my custom tune to all the tools or if i can make my custom tune as default tune block that also works
I tried to add it directly in editorjs config like,
    editorInstance.current = new EditorJS({
      holder: editorContainer.current,
      tools: {
        
        header: {
          class: Header,
          inlineToolbar: true
        },
        list: {
          class: List,
          inlineToolbar: true,
          tunes: BackgroundColorTune
        },
        Image: SimpleImage
        // Add more tools here as needed
      },
      defaultBlock:"BackgroundColorTune",
      tunes: ["BackgroundColorTune"]
    });

But not workng

Before everything please read this instruction for a better understanding
based on instruction article

Each Block Tune must have at least isTune static getter and the render() method.

well to have a tune tool in all of your blocks you should modify your code as below:

as this is a tune tool you should add the below code before the constructor of your custom tune file:
static get isTune() {
    return true;
}


you should use a render method to render your tune options it means you should change the renderSettings to render and please remember that you have to implement the click action on your options so for example when you want to apply some CSS changes on your block by clicking each option which CSS class must add to the wrapper class attribute

you should wrap your block content using wrap method, highly suggest you read this part of instructions for a better understanding



This method is called on Block render and allows you to wrap Block's content to modify it's styles

class MyBlockTune {

     ...

       wrap(blockContent) {
       const myWrapper = document.createElement('div');

        myWrapper.append(blockContent);

        myWrapper.style.fontSize = '0.9em';

       return myWrapper;
        }
  }


finally you have to represent it in your editorjs config like it's one of your tools. don't worry editorjs knows that it's a tune tool and after that add this tune to any tool you want by passing tunes property to the desired tool
editorInstance.current = new EditorJS({
  holder: editorContainer.current,
  tools: {

    header: {
      class: Header,
      inlineToolbar: true
    },
    list: {
      class: List,
      inlineToolbar: true,
      tunes: ["backgroundColorTuneTool"]
    },
    Image: SimpleImage
    // Add more tools here as needed,

    backgroundColorTuneTool: {
       class: BackgroundColorTune
    },
  },
  defaultBlock:"BackgroundColorTune",
});



hope it works! don't forget to read the instructions
